# Requesting geolocation with a minimum accuracy requirement

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, ip-geolocation

Suppose I'm bound to use one provider, say **GPS**. I have a minimum **accuracy requirement** and I need a **single** signal that satisfies it. What are the best practices?

What I'm doing is I call "requestLocationUpdates" to get continuous locations, then check each one for accuracy and finally call "removeUpdates" when I get a good one.

Should I be doing this with **minTime** and **minDistance** set to 0 because the accuracy comes randomly enough? Or should I set some special values to it because, by the nature of GPS, it's likely to keep giving me similar accuracy unless I move away (say from buildings?) or I give it time (say for random atmosphere conditions or satellite positions to change?)? If so, which values would it be?

Note: According to [this text](http://www.littleeye.co/blog/2013/03/29/understanding-gps-resource-usage/), GPS uses more power to get the fix than to get locations afterwords. Which for me means that "**requestSingleUpdate**" is no good with an accuracy requirement. Is this right?

If you're using **NETWORK** instead, will it work in the same way?

Comment: I mention NETWORK as well because our accuracy requirement (35m) is satisfiable by it sometimes (according to our tests). We want to preferably use NETWORK to save power but switch to GPS and back every time the first begins to consistently give bad accuracy.

Comment: interesting... in my experience NETWORK typically gives ~100m accuracy when in range of WiFi and on the order of 1000m when only using cell towers.

Answer (score 0):

In your case only solution works:

Set Provider to GPS only, set time and accuracy to best (0),
and decide yourself, e.g by reading attribute estimatedAccuracy from location.

Its true, the initial position finding needs most power, so it makes no sense to enable and disable GPS every 20s. Unfortunetly I dont knwo where the threshold in minutes is where it saves battery when temporary disabling GPS.

The acuiracy requirement currently makes only sense to distinuish between GPS (3-6m) and Network (GSM cell: 1000m) WLAN sometimes will be better than GSM cell locationing, but often is not available, and less reliable.
If you, for your app decide that you need more or less acurate position, then an accuracy requirfement, other than "best" make no sense.